# Why I cannot see the XML files for XML views?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

When I use a XML view for a page in SAPUI5, and I open Developer Tools on Google Chrome and check, under the "Sources" tab, the directory that has the ".controller" file, I cannot see the "view.xml" file. Why does it happen? Does the browser "excludes" the XML file after it is processed by the UI5 core? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sources tab in Google Chrome Developer tools is meant for debugging the logic of your application. It allows you to add break-points, see your calls stack and observe/tinker with intermediate variable values.

As SAPUI5 XML views don't contain any logic, it doesn't make sense to show it in the sources tab, as there is no logic to debug. You can see your XML files in the network tab though, if you just want to do some inspection on its contents.

More info on debugging using the source tab can be found here:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Answer (score 1):

I think that the sources tab only displays some file types. It doesn't display .json files either.

You should be able to access unparsed XML files through Network tab.